# Is every sequence of natural numbers representable by an arithmetic term?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Definition.** Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $A = [m] = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n < m \}$. A sequence of natural numbers $a: A \to B$ is representable by an arithmetic term $t(n)$ ($n$ is a free variable in $t$) iff $a_n = t(n)$, for all $n \in A$.

For example, $(2, 3, 4)$ is represented by $t(n) = n + 1$, because $t(1) = 2$, $t(2) = 3$ and $t(3) = 4$.

My question is whether every sequence of natural numbers is representable in the above sense. Here are some corollaries, depending on the answer of this question.

- Yes. Here, it is important to distinguish multiple options. These have a bearing on my original motivating question: whether any such sequence exists that it uniquely determines its extension (by one element) when we demand that it is described by an arithmetic term.

  - For every sequence, there are multiple terms which represent it. This implies that the answer to my original motivating question is "No."
  - There exists a sequence such that only one term represents it. This implies that the answer to my original motivating question is "Yes." The term itself provides this extension (simply look at its value at $n + 1$).
- No. This does not tell us much. Weirdly, there would be sequences of natural numbers not describable by an arithmetic term. Note that the answer to my motivating question could still be "Yes" in this case, since we only need one such special sequence, which also happens to be representable.

The only complication I see here is the definition of $t$, namely, which operations we should allow in it. Until a more lucid suggestion arrives, I will fix these to addition and multiplication.

Comment: Given $n$ points $(x_i,y_i)$ with $x_i \in A, y_i \in B$ you can always find an interpolation polynomial $p$ of degree $\le n-1$ such that $p(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Between my comment and yours, the OP will have to clarify that.

Comment: My bad, I got a bit confused. Do hang in for the edit! :)

Comment: @dxiv Excellent! This answers my question for finite $A$s. Now, it would be interesting to know whether these $p$s are unique. Do consider posting this as an answer!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes, all languages with countable signatures are countable. The problem, though, is that a term can describe multiple sequences. For example, $t(n) = n + 1$ represents $(2, 3, 4)$ as well as $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ etc.

Comment: @dxiv Also, to capture the essence of sequences, I will make $A$ an initial slice of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Godbless The interpolating polynomial of minimal degree is in fact unique by the [interpolation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_theorem). However, it is not clear what you are after. The post repeatedly refers to an "*original motivating question*" but you never say what that is.

Comment: @dxiv This is the original motivating question:
"whether any such sequence exists that it uniquely determines its extension (by one element) when we demand that it is described by an arithmetic term."

Comment: @dxiv I think you answered it. Per my definition of an arithmetic terms, only polynomial terms are arithmetic terms. Because for every finite sequence, only one such polynomial exists, as you claim, it is the case that it provides the only possible continuation. Thank you. Do consider posting an answer. :)

Comment: This is peculiar, though, as I remember once hearing that there exists a rule for every finite sequence which continues this sequence with an arbitrary natural number.

Comment: @Godbless "*only one such polynomial exists*" $\;-\;$ That's not true, and it's not what I wrote. Quoting from my earlier comment: "*the interpolating polynomial* ***of minimal degree*** *is in fact unique*". For example, the sequence $(2,3,4)$ can be generated by $n+1$, but also by $-n^3 + 6 n^2 - 10 n + 7$. However, only the former is *of minimal degree*.

Comment: @dxiv Of course, my apologies. Can any polynomial of minimal degree be extended in such a fashion? If so, the answer to my question is "No."

Comment: @Godbless Choose any $x$ then you'll always find a polynomial of degree $\le 3$ that generates $(2,3,4,x)$.